# trying to access my AWS Glacier vaults returns an empty list, even though I have existing vaults in the region

Tags: amazon-glacier

I was trying to delete a Glacier vault which turned out to be impossible to do from the console, as the vault was not empty. I learned that I had to use the AWS cli to first delete all the archives from the vault, so I first try to list all my vaults in Ireland (EU) using the command:

aws glacier list-vaults --account-id - --region us-west-1

This returns:

```
{
"VaultList": []
}
```

To be sure that I'm logged in properly, I tried another command, like 'aws s3 ls', which correctly returns all my S3 buckets.

I am, in fact, using the AWS cli for the first time, so I might be missing something trivial here, but I feel rather stuck at the moment. Does anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The solution is probably to fix the --region parameter.